# how to add custom view to interface builder in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, interface-builder, parse-platform

I am using a framework which only includes header .h files.  There is a view called PFImageView which I have added to story boards.  I did this by first dragging a UIImageView to a custom prototype cell.  I then changed the UIImageView class to PFImageView.  I then dragged the view to my class to create an IBOutlet.

When I run the app, I get the error:

```
Unknown class PFImageView in Interface Builder file.
[UIImageView setFile:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x97a9150
```

The framework is added to project target. The .m file is not viewable/available in the framework. Is there anything else I need to do to have interface builder recognize this file?

Comment: @itruf Possible duplicate? Atma himself posted both questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a subclass of UIView, but not UIImageView?

Or, why not just alloc init the PFImageView and then addSubview?

Comment: PFImageView is subclass of UIImageView (https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFImageView.html)